# Woocommerce new fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

How can I add 2 new fields on the same row? Now They are on 2 rows.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','reorder_woo_fields');

function reorder_woo_fields($fields) {
     $fields2['billing']['billing_ico'] = array(
        'label'     => __('ICO', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('ICO', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('form-row-first'),
    'clear'     => true
     );
            $fields2['billing']['billing_dic'] = array(
        'label'     => __('DIC', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('DIC', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('form-row-last'),
    'clear'     => true
     );   

    return $fields2;
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use your class names form-row-first & form-row-last in CSS and set them to a specified width and display inline.